# Problem in accessing Kafka present in Azure VM

Tags: java, azure, apache-kafka

I have created a Virtual Machine in Azure and setup Apache Kafka inside it. Now I want to access the Kafka from my local machine but it keeps on giving me the connection not established error after stucking for a while in **kafkaProducer.send(record)**, this is the producer code :

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KafkaIP);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
        try {

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

                ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("sec", Integer.toString(1),"Hello"); 
/* GETS STUCK IN THE FOLLOWING LINE FOR VERY LONG*/
                kafkaProducer.send(record);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have uncommented and placed the public IP in the property **advertised.listeners** inside **server.properties** file. Both 9092 & 2181 ports are open for the source.
The same thing worked for the AWS EC2 instance. Is there any other modification that I have to do for accessing Kafka which inside Azure VM?

Comment: Is you Azure VM exposed to the internet? Did you configured advertised host in Kafka's `server.properties` correctly?

Comment: I tried pinging the VM from my local machine and it was responding correctly. I only modified this property and placed public IP instead of the text advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<public ip>:9092